# If You Look vs. If You're Looking: When advertising a Product

Tags: word-choice, tenses, present-tense, determiners, present-progressive

Is it correct to use "if you look for" instead of "if you're looking for" when promoting a product?

"If you look for creamy peanut butter spread, you may message me."

I used "look for" because the progressive tense, "You are looking for" refers to action that is currently happening.

Also, should there be an "a" in creamy peanut butter? I believe there shouldn't be an "a" because spread is an uncountable noun.

Thank you!

Comment: ***When*** *you look …* would sound more natural in conjunction with the present tense. Plus, it's better for advertising to say that somebody definitely will, rather than only making it a possibility.

Comment: (Also, while *spread* can be a mass noun, it can also be countable. In this context, it's your choice.)

Comment: Regarding my first question, but is it correct to use "if you look for" in that scenario?

Comment: @BeaRose *If you look* is grammatical, but it's not as idiomatic as *when you look*.

Comment: Thank you very much! Will take note of your suggestion on the usage of when and if in advertising a product. But one last question, you said it's up to me whether I will treat spread as a mass noun or not. Does it mean both are correct regardless of the presence of a?

Comment: As an advertising line, the more idiomatic version is *"If you are looking for creamy peanut butter spread, ..."* The present continuous is correct as it implies that the person might be actively seeking a "creamy peanut butter spread," PS "*you may message me."* does not sound very idiomatic to me, but it will depend on the context - and you have given none.

Comment: It seems that both of you agree that the two are grammatical, but the former is less idiomatic. You included an "a" in creamy peanut butter, does it mean there should be an "a" before creamy? Thank you!

Comment: @BeaRose Yes, both ***a*** *spread* and *spread* are correct in this context. But they do have different meanings. If you say ***a*** *spread*, you are suggesting they are looking for a *jar* of spread, a *brand* of spread, or a *type* of spread. Without the *a*, it's just spread in general.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Jason! But I'm confused. Are you saying that "for creamy peanut butter spread" is correct? I asked about this, and they said that the presence of "a" is needed in said context.

Comment: @BeaRose Yes, that's what I'm saying. I said *spread* rather than *creamy peanut butter spread* for the sake of simplicity. Using the indefinite article or not (either is acceptable) applies all spreads, regardless of their texture and flavour …

Comment: Based on your answers, I can conclude that the former is grammatical, but is less idiomatic. That the sentence, thought correct,  could be improved to sound more natural. I've learned a lot from you all! Thank you very much.